# adding custom Columns to Angular Material Exporter

Tags: angular-material, export-to-excel, angular-material-table, custom-events, mat-table-exporter

I have a question about the Angular material exporter.

Is it possible to expand table columns for export or show hidden columns in excel export?

I have a column memory usage. it looks something like "200 mb out of 300 mb". can i remove the strings only in export? and change the value to "200/300" for example?

Unfortunately, I can't quite figure it out from the documentation. Thanks for your answer